# need to change the URL to friendly url in joomla1.5

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, seo

I am using joomla 1.5.23 and want to make the URL SEO friendly..  so for that I have used the joomla component JoomSEF 3.4.0 version for this purpose...  by using this I have suceeced to change the URL to derired one of my likings but the links are not working..  For make this links to work do i have change the joomla .Htaccess file...

If there is any other relevant components are there.. then also please suggest..  any kind of suggestion will be greatly appreciated...  thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Joomla supports SEO URLs without any third party components.

From the administration menu select Site then Global Configuration. You will see the SEO section on the right hand side. You'll see a warning next to Apache mod_rewrite that reminds you to rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess